# How to upgrade my desktop CPU to a better one?

Tags: cpu, desktop

Well, this may be too broad of a question. Let me break it down a bit:

1. Type of CPU, is it must be following some sort of similar standard so to be able to work? What standard? (My CPU is Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3260)
2. Type of mother board? Does it matter? If yes, what standard that I need to check?
3. Installation. should I open up my box and take a look how CPU is installed on the motherboard? Does it matter?
4. How about fan? big and small? Does it matter?
5. Anything else?

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures. It's hard to read, doesn't resize well, doesn't get parsed by search engines and is unreadable for visually impaired people using screen readers. You can [edit] your question and get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Type of CPU, is it must be following some sort of similar standard so to be able to work? What standard?

You need to look for the socket of the CPU/Motherboard. Your motherboard will support a certain kind of CPU's and depending on the age, it may support up to a certain CPU, so you need to look for that.

> 2. Type of mother board? Does it matter? If yes, what standard that I need to check?

You only need to check your current motherboard to see what the maximum CPU is that it can take. If you go through the route to replace the motherboard, you can just as well buy a new pc because then, you are not limited anymore to what your current pc has and can be upgraded to.

> 3. Installation. should I open up my box and take a look how CPU is installed on the motherboard? Does it matter?

No. You only need to do this when you are going to upgrade the pc.

> 4. How about fan? big and small? Does it matter?

This depends on the CPU that you buy. After you find a CPU that you can upgrade to, look for a cooler that supports that CPU.

Answer (score 1):

> Type of CPU
>
> Type of mother board

The motherboard pretty much controls which CPUs you can upgrade to.  You should start by obtaining and reviewing the manual to your motherboard which should illustrate/explain your options.

Upgrade ability is dependent on two things.  The first is the chipset, which is a component on the motherboard.  CPUs require a specific chipset to work.  Note that just because your board has chipset X doesn't mean it can take every CPU that works with chipset X - so again, get the manual and read it.

The second is the motherboard socket - it must be of the same type and number of pins as the CPU you want to put in it.  Newer CPUs often have more pins and require different sockets.

In some instances a UEFI upgrade may be needed for a new CPU to work.  You should do this (probably a good idea to simply apply the latest update anyway) and reset settings to the default before physically changing out the CPU.

> Installation. should I open up my box and take a look how CPU is installed on the motherboard? Does it matter?

CPUs are keyed and will go in only one way.  Plus, motherboard sockets are now "land grid arrays" - meaning the CPU rests on top of the pins and doesn't actually plug into anything.  Obey static electricity precautions.

> How about fan? big and small? Does it matter?

Your existing fan should work, if you are upgrading a CPU.  There's many options with regard to fans - quiet fans with pretty lights are more expensive than loud ugly fans.